# VBA to Copy 3 Sheets in a Fouth One

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem making a little VBA to copy/paste some datas. I looked around and didn't really find any post who talk of my problem.

Here is my problem: I have 3 worksheets who need to be copied on a fourth worksheet. Each worksheet have between 200 and 650 lines. On the three sheets, it's the columns A, I, J, K, L, M,N who need to be copied on the columns A, C, D, H, I, M, N. The copy paste action need to start on the first blank line of the fourth sheet. This is the last constraint who make it a lot more difficult than I expected. I tried two ways and haven't managed to make it works.

Here is the code (one way is in comments form)

```
Dim Sh as Worksheet
Dim i as Integer
For Each Sh In Sheets(Array("Janvier", "Février", "Mars"))

For i = 4 To 650
  Worksheets("Sh").Range("A & i").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Calculs").Range("A" &    Sheets("Calculs").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
  Worksheets("Sh").Range("I & i:J & i").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Calculs").Range("I" & Sheets("Calculs").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
  Worksheets("Sh").Range("K & i:L & i").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Calculs").Range("K" & Sheets("Calculs").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
  Worksheets("Sh").Range("M & i:N & i").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Calculs").Range("M" & Sheets("Calculs").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

  'Sheets("Calculs").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Sheets(Sh).Range("A4:A650").Value
  'Sheets("Calculs").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Sheets(Sh).Range("I4:J650").Value
  'Sheets("Calculs").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Sheets(Sh).Range("K4:L650").Value
  'Sheets("Calculs").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Sheets(Sh).Range("M4:n650").Value
  Next i
Next Sh
```

My error after executing the code not in comments form is "Subscript out of range". Can you propose me a better way to code this.

Thank you for your help, Olivier

Comment: `Worksheets("Sh")` should just be `Sh`.  And you should avoid using UsedRange like that in a loop: instead grab the last row into a variable before you start copying, and increment it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .Cells method instead of .Range. Like so:

```
Worksheets("Sh").Cells(i, 1) ...
```

Where the first parameter is your row and the second is your columns (A=1, B=2, ect).

Comment: I don't have any error but the code takes forever to run. I let it run for 10 minutes and no results appeared on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, rw As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Calculs")

    'get first empty row
    Set rw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Sh In Sheets(Array("Janvier", "Février", "Mars"))
        For i = 4 To 650

            Sh.Range("A" & i).Copy rw.Cells(1, "A")
            Sh.Range("I" & i & ":J" & i).Copy rw.Cells(1, "I")
            Sh.Range("K" & i & ":L" & i).Copy rw.Cells(1, "K")
            Sh.Range("M" & i & ":N" & i).Copy rw.Cells(1, "M")

            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
        Next i
    Next Sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, you get me exactly what I needed. With this code I'll be able to create cleaner code for my next applications.